# Aria: Length of DECIMAL entries incorrect

Tags: size, decimal, mariadb, mysql-python, sqldatatypes

I'm having a problem regarding the entries of an ARIA database's table. Said table should be structured like this:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE grid;

CREATE TABLE `grid` 
(`meas_time` decimal(11,1) unsigned NOT NULL,
`meas_id` tinyint(2) unsigned NOT NULL,
`frequency` float(6,4) unsigned NOT NULL,
`voltage` float(7,4) unsigned NOT NULL,
`phase` float(9,8) unsigned NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`meas_time`,`meas_id`)) 
ENGINE=Aria 
DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 
PAGE_CHECKSUM=1
```

The data inserted into this table has always the same format which should exactly meet the structure outlined above. However, this only seems to work for 'meas_id', 'frequency', 'voltage' and 'phase' - and not for 'meas_time':

```
SELECT FROM grid PROCEDURE ANALYSE();
```

First (left) half of answer table:

```
Field_name              Min_value       Max_value       Min_length  Max_length  
archiv.grid.meas_time   1473152369.8    1475751654.0    22          22          
archiv.grid.meas_id     1               1               1           1   
archiv.grid.frequency   49.5832         59.9998         7           7   
archiv.grid.voltage     101.3357        812.5874        8           8   
archiv.grid.phase       0.00043659      6.99986124      10          10
```

Second (right) half of answer table:

```
Empties_or_zeros    Nulls   Avg_value_or_avg_length   Std           Optimal_fieldtype 
0                   0       1474509648.88213          845302.17909  DECIMAL(21, 1) NOT NULL
0                   0       1.0000                    0.0000        ENUM('1') NOT NULL
0                   0       50.0250                   0.3668        FLOAT(6,4) NOT NULL
0                   0       289.5351                  40.3620       FLOAT(7,4) NOT NULL
0                   0       3.15090137                1.80843320    FLOAT(9,8) NOT NULL
```

All data is inserted in the same way - by a python script making use of the mySQLdb package. It specifically inserts stings of the right length to the database, e.g.:

```
command = "INSERT INTO grid VALUES ('" + str(timestamp)[:12] + \
          "', '" + str(frequency)[:7] + "', '" + str(voltage)[:8] + \
          "', '" + str(phase)[:10] + "');"
self.localCursor.execute(command)
self.localDB.commit()
```

The database management system I'm running is the following:

```
Server Version: 5.5.52-MariaDB-1ubuntu0.14.04.1 - (Ubuntu)
```

Obviously, this discrepancy is a problem as it unneccessarily inflates the size of my database. Does anyone know, why this is happening and how I could stop it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The internal format for storing a decimal column changed (afaik in MySQL 5.0 or 5.1) and the changes weren't updated in procedure analyse(). So just ignore the values.

You should definetly consider to change the key order in your primary key to avoid an index scan if your where condition uses maes_id.

Comment: Alright.. But the values 'row length' and 'row size' are accurate or do they have the same problem? And regarding the composite primary key: The order of keys affects the speed of querys as the first key is being used first? In that case, I should definitely change those. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do *not* use `FLOAT(m,n)`; it leads to double-rounding and potentially data corruption.  Either use plain `FLOAT` (for scientific quantities like those) or `DECIMAL(m,n)` (for money).

`PROCEDURE ANALYSE` is deprecated.  Sure it has some use, but that is too bad.

`ANALYSE` probably does everything in `DOUBLE`.  Anyway, what you you want for the average of these three *integers*: `1` and `2` and `1`?  `1.3333333` is the obvious answer, but who controls the number of decimal places?  Wouldn't it be 'wrong' to round to the original datatype and get `1`?

Comment: Thank you for your further advice (-> double-rounding), but I do not get the meaning of your last paragraph.. Is it regarding the double-rounding again? Or is it aiming at something else?

Comment: Not aimed at double-rounding, but aimed at how many decimal places to put on an average -- related to the question's Title.

Comment: Oh, well, in this case, the number of decimal places is selected based upon the accuracy of the underlying measurment system. The measurement system delivers the data, the database stores it. But I agree with you, oftentimes it would be a hard call to make.